# push notification not sent for production even it is connected to APNS

Tags: ios, push-notification, ssl-certificate, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I want to implement push notifications in my application.
First, I try it for development side, it is working. Now, I am testing it for production, it is not working.
I already changed sandbox to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 in my php.

I created production.pem with this steps.

$ openssl x509 -in aps_developer_identity.cer -inform der -out PushChatCert.pem

$ openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushChatKey.pem -in PushChatKey.p12

Enter Import Password: MAC verified OK Enter PEM pass phrase: Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:

$ cat PushChatCert.pem PushChatKey.pem > ck.pem

and I uploaded my ck.pem to my shared host. It is nothing errors but it does not push notification.

in my php ,it said : Connected to APNS Message successfully delivered.

But, no push notifications are received in devices.

Please help, thank you

Comment: Isn't this literally the same question and the one you asked two hours prior? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504726/apple-push-notification-is-not-working-for-distribution-but-working-for-developm

Answer (score 0):

It is not Necessary that the Push Notifications arrives always but still u should need to make sure that u have updated the new profiles and passphrase and sandbox

Comment: yes, I am sure that I put the correct passphrase and certificate, and I remove sandbox because for distribution

Comment: please test the notification locally on your machine rather put on the  server then u will be able to make sure that your iOS end is good if you still not able to received then you should need to make pem file again