# Ports number needed to open to receive push notification from APNS

Tags: ios, push-notification, port, apple-push-notifications

I would like to understand the cycle of APNS with my web server to receive push notification. I open the port 2195 from my webserver in the (out side), do I need another port to open it in my sever to receive the push notification??? because still not received it.

please help!

Comment: The device receives push notification not your server, your server should send push notifications.

Comment: so all what I need is to open port number 2195 in the (out side)??? what about 2196?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, port 2195 open. With APNS, you only send out things. Apple doesn't send you anything back unless you're using the feedback gateway, which I guess is not your case...

Your server do not receive push notifications. It only sends requests to Apple, which then sends notifications to iOS devices or MacOS desktops.

If your device did not receive and your server code is being able to establish a connection with apple, much probably your push cert is not uploaded to your server or it has permission problems or it was not properly generated at your iOS dev website.

p.s. if you're sending OUT things, your port logically should be open from inside (outbound) in your server

Comment: please can I follow with you my steps, and tell you what I have did, by email?

Comment: Sure I can follow your steps, but I suggest we do it here. Should be no problem.

Comment: Did this end up working for you? Seems the same problem you have asked before. People gave you good answers, but you didn't accept any of them.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504726/apple-push-notification-is-not-working-for-distribution-but-working-for-developm

Comment: look all what you tell me to do, I already did, and the push notification works for me in dev mode, but the problem is for distribution mode, and I followed the same steps I did in dev mode, but sure there are some modifications like remove sandbox, and cert for production,... for this reason I am lost, and I gave up

Comment: Can you establish connections with Apple via port 2195? If so, how do you know that? Does your PHP code spit out any error or message? Was your production cert properly downloaded, processed via terminal and uploaded to your server? How are the permissions of your cert file at the server? Are you sure you're calling the right (development/production) cert ? Are you calling the right (dev/prod) gateway? Are you sending messages to a valid token? Same app has different tokens for dev or production mode. If you cover all these items, I'm sure you'll find the problem

Comment: From my experience, the problem is never at Apple. It's always something between your cert, gateway URL or tokens that you're trying to send msgs to.

Comment: Also don't expect to use the production gateway + certificate to send messages to a not published app locally compiled by Xcode. They will simply never arrive.

Comment: yes for sure I know, I already publish my app to appstore, and I receive the notification alert to verify if I want to receive them, can u tell me what are the permissions of cert file at the server?

Comment: Sure, please try chmod 400. I hope it works some magic for you.

Comment: look, how can I get the device token for production, I have devtoken for my iPad which I got it for development mode, You said that maybe there is a difference between devtokens for development mode and production, I lost in database where is my iPad?

Comment: My app sends the device token upon login and stores them in a database, then I can see them. I didn't say "maybe" there's a difference of dev and prod tokens. I said that's for sure. Your development token will not reach your published app. How are you retrieving your published app token?

Comment: "I have devtoken for my iPad which I got it for development mode" - This really raises my eyebrows since you're talking about production mode.